# React-typescript: Nested map function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-operator

I am using React typescript for my app. I used redux and saga for state management. I fetched the data and successfully display on browser with google maps. If anyone hover the properties it will display on the map. Now I have decided to use search option to search the properties. I filtered the properties' name then includes to my local state.  My search input works fine in console. I map the state and try to display the properties, it shows the same properties names multiple times. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXC1.png). I don't know how to fix it. **I edited the question and remove the ternary operator.**

```
    import React, { useEffect, lazy, useState } from "react";
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import ErrorBoundary from "components/errorBoundary";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import { IDashboardProperties } from "../../state/properties/reducer";
    import { fetchProperties } from "../../state/properties/actions";
    import { IIssueListItem } from "../../state/issues/types";
    import { fetchIssuesList } from "../../state/issues/actions";
    import { ICombinedReducers } from "../../state";
    import TestMaps from "./TestMaps";
    import LogoSpinner from "components/loaders/logoSpinner";
    const SectionTemplate = lazy(() =>
      import(`../../templates/primary/sectionTemplate`)
    );
    export interface ITestNewListProps {
      className?: string;
    }

    const Test = ({ className }: ITestNewListProps) => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const properties: IDashboardProperties["data"] | undefined = useSelector(
        (state: ICombinedReducers["properties"]) => state.properties.list.data
      );
      const issues: IIssueListItem | undefined = useSelector(
        (state: ICombinedReducers) => state.issues.list.data
      );
      useEffect(() => {
        // fetch the properties data from the api if we don't already have it
        !properties && dispatch(fetchProperties({}));
      }, [dispatch, properties]);

      useEffect(() => {
        !issues && dispatch(fetchIssuesList());
      }, [dispatch, issues]);

      const [hoveredProperty, setHoveredProperty] = useState<string | undefined>(
        undefined
      );
      const [searchItem, setsearchItem] = useState(``); //THIS IS THE SEARCH STATE


      console.log(`properties`, properties);
      console.log(`issues`, issues);

      const propertiesSorted: any[] = [];
      const markersSorted: any[] = [];
      let propertyInfo: any = {};

      properties?.forEach((currProperty) => {
        propertiesSorted.push({
          name: currProperty.name,
          uuid: currProperty.uuid,
          address: "",
          aliases: "",
          city: "",
          isHovered: hoveredProperty === currProperty.uuid,
        });

        if (hoveredProperty === currProperty.uuid) {


          propertyInfo = {
            name: currProperty.name,
            total: currProperty.serviceRequests.uncompleted.length,
            old: currProperty.serviceRequests.uncompletedAfterFiveDays.length,
            reportedToday: currProperty.serviceRequests.createdToday.length,
            task: currProperty.tasks.overdue.length,
          };
        }

        currProperty.addresses.forEach((i: any, index) => {
          markersSorted.push({
            key: index,
            lat: i.coordinates.latitude,
            lng: i.coordinates.longitude,
            name: i.property.name,
            isHovered: hoveredProperty === currProperty.uuid,
          });
        });
      });

      const Search = (e: any) => { //THIS IS THE INPUT FUNCTION
        setsearchItem(e.target.value);
      }; 
      const nameFilter: any | [] = properties?.filter((list) => {
        return list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase());
      }); //IN HERE I FILTERED THE PROPERTIES AND ADD IT TO THE `searchItem` STATE.

      console.log(`Name filter`, nameFilter); // search result works 

      console.log("propertyInfoCopy", propertyInfo);

      return (
        <ErrorBoundary id="TestNewListErrorBoundary">
          <SectionTemplate>
            <div className={className}>
              <div className="properties-list-sidebar">
                <input placeholder="search property" onChange={Search} />
                <br /> <br />
                <div>
//THIS IS WHERE I AM DOING MAPPING
                  {nameFilter?.map((i: any) => (
                    <div>
                      {propertiesSorted?.map((i) => (
                        <div

                          className={
                            i.isHovered
                              ? "property-item property-item-hovered"
                              : "property-item"
                          }
                          key={i.uuid}
                          onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredProperty(i.uuid)}
                        >
                          Name: {i.name}
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>{" "}
              </div>
              <div className="properties-list-map">
                {hoveredProperty && (
                  <div
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: 100,
                      right: 30,
                      zIndex: 2,
                      background: "pink",
                      padding: 20,
                    }}
                  >
                    Name: {propertyInfo.name} <br />
                    <h2>Service requests</h2>
                    <p>Unassigned: {propertyInfo.old}</p>
                    <p>Uncompleted: {propertyInfo.total}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
                {properties ? (
                  <TestMaps markers={markersSorted} />
                ) : (
                  <LogoSpinner />
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </SectionTemplate>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      );
    };

    Test.displayName = `Test`;

    export default styled(Test)`
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      align-content: flex-start;
      .properties-list-sidebar {
        flex: 0;
        width: 300px;
        flex-basis: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        background: white;
      }
      .properties-list-map {
        flex: 1;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .property-item {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        &:hover {
          background-color: yellow;
        }
      }
      .Notfound {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        color: red;
      }
      .property-item-hovered {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    `;
```

Comment: Please point to the mappping specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you filter on the properties array, but what you are rendering is the propertiesSorted array on line 108, which you only push to, and never remove anything from. And you render the whole propertiesSorted array once for each item that nameFilter contains.

This untested snippet doesn't contain your propertiesSorted array, so it doesn't fix your code, but maybe it can get you started.

```
   {nameFilter.length ? nameFilter?.map((i: any, name, uuid, isHovered ) => 
        <div
            className={
                isHovered
                ? "property-item property-item-hovered"
                : "property-item"
            }
            key={uuid}
            onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredProperty(uuid)}
            >
               Name: {name}
            </div>
            ) : (
              <h1>Sorry property not found</h1>
            )
          )}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. if I don't propertiesSorted map method it will not gona display the data which I already render it. Currently I have 6 properties, that's why I am getting 6 repeated names because it loops 6 time.  Is there any I can loop once? sorry for my english. But I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Instead of ternary operation, is there any way i can add or includes the `i` in the `propertiesSorted map` method?

Comment: Maybe you can do const nameFilter: any | [] = propertiesSorted?.filter((list) => {
        return list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase());
      });

Comment: Great, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `nameFilter` variable is not getting updated.

```
const Test = ({ className }: ITestNewListProps) => {
  const [filterNames, setFilteredNames] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 /*
  . REST OF THE CODE
  .
 */
  const nameFilter: any | [] = properties?.filter((list) => { //In 
    return list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase());
  });
  setFilteredNames(nameFilter);// Set state variable here
```

Use `filteredNames` in return statement instead of `nameFilter`

Comment: Thank you for reply. Just out of curiosity, Why should I  add the variables to other state?

Comment: I think my code logic is ok. I am making mistakes in mapping.

Comment: Regular JS variable won't update in React hooks after initial assignment. So if you're looking for any update in variable you must use state variable. This is the reason why you are not getting same values instead of filter ones.

Comment: Can you please show me in code. because the sample you showed me, it did not work :(